# How to put command line parameter to shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a executable shell script name project2. Following is one of the instruction my teacher gave me on the project.

> This script must accept at least one
>   command line parameter: the directory
>   where its output is to be placed. If
>   that directory is not given on the
>   command line, the script should use a
>   reasonable default directory.

Can you please tell me how can I make my script accept a command line. I haven't done anything like that before. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are using bash, and not some other shell, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For `bash`, command line parameters are stored in `$1`, `$2`, and so on, while `$#` will give you the count. In addition, `shift` can be used to shift them all "left" by one position and drop the count.

The following script is a good starting point for understanding how the parameters work:

```
echo $#
while [[ $# -gt 0 ]] ; do
    echo "$1"
    shift
done
```

When you run it with:

```
./myprog.sh hello there my name is "pax     diablo"
```

the output is:

```
6
hello
there
my
name
is
pax     diablo
```

The basic idea of your assignment is:

- check the parameter count to see if it's zero.
- if it is zero, set a variable to some useful default.
- if it isn't zero, set that variable based on the first parameter.
- do whatever you have to do with that variable.

Comment: wow, thanks for the detailed information pax. Now I understand how it works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this section](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/othertypesv.html) of [Advanced Bash Scripting guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/).

I recommend you to read whole guide.